# starting headless firefox with Xvfb does not work

Tags: firefox, headless, xvfb

I try to run firefox in headless mode for selenium.

$xvfb-run firefox  seems to work.

I run firefox through selenium so i cannot run xvfb-run directly.

So i start

> Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &

and then

> set DISPLAY:=1
>   env DISPLAY:=1

Still when i run firefox i get

> Error: no display specified

I run on centos 6 and firefox 38 ESR.

What can be done?

Answer (score 0):

can you try that?
    export DISPLAY=:1

Comment: unfortunately i have a tcsh shell so i cannot use this

Comment: setenv DISPLAY=:1    :)

Answer (score 0):

start firefox with --display arg

```
/usr/bin/firefox --display=:1
```