# How to execute Firefox on Centos?

Tags: firefox, centos, headless, xvfb

Firefox version Mozilla Firefox 40.0
CentOS 64 bit
Xvfb is installed and running.

But when i ran the **firefox** command. It shows following error message

Error: no display specified

Comment: Try running `yum install gdk-pixbuf2` and run firefox again.

Comment: already installed the latest version

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32480000/3124333 ?

Comment: @SiKing have you found any solution